# Attempting to invert a Binary Tree in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I've recently started getting into functional programming and have just started to learn Haskell. I am attempting to invert a binary tree and I have the following so far:

```
data Tree a = Tip | Bin (Tree a) a (Tree a) deriving (Show,Eq)

mirror :: Tree a -> Tree a
mirror(Bin l v r) = (mirror r) Bin v (mirror l)
```

However, I don't exactly understand why I get the following error: Couldn't match expected type `‘(Tree a0 -> a0 -> Tree a0 -> Tree a0)`. Can anyone explain where I am getting confused?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put the data constructor first here, so it should be:

```
mirror :: Tree a -> Tree a
mirror(Bin l v r) = Bin (mirror r) v (mirror l)
```

By using `(mirror r) Bin v mirror l`, you call `Bin` as a parameter on the result of `mirror r`, so `((mirror r) Bin)`. But that does not make much sense.

Note that you will need to add a case for `Tip` as well, since right now, your function does not cover all possible values.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was having some trouble wrapping my head around the fundamentals of functional programming. As for the base case I wrote the following: mirror @e(Tip) = e.

Comment: @CarlosRomero An equivalent formulation would be `mirror Tip = Tip`. I would only use the `e@Tip` construction for longer expressions, but there's nothing *wrong* with it if you like it here.